# How to play multiple animations at once?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to play 2 animations at once

for example,
my arms have the animations: `static`, `running_swing` & `drawing weapon`
my legs have the animations: `static`, `running`

and I want to play them both, simultaneously in any combination like:
arms `running_swing` & legs `running` or
arms `drawing weapon` & legs `running`

so far the only way I found was to create 2 separate `AnimationPlayer`s
and play them one after the other:

```
$AnimationPlayerArms.play("running_swing");
$AnimationPlayerLegs.play("running");  # but this approach too isn't simultaneous
```

or use `Tween` but that approach also fails because it becomes really difficult the more the animations are complicated

So is there any way or method that I might be missing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `AnimationTree`.

As usual, set the `AnimationPlayer`, and set `active` to true.

For the `tree_root` set new `AnimationNodeBlendTree`. Then make an Animation node for each of your animations. Connected them together via Blend nodes (I'd use `0.5` for the blend value). And I'll add a Seek node at the end to control it.

[image: AnimationNodeBlendTree setup]

The `AnimationTree` would have added parameters for the blend values and the seek value. Setting the seek parameter to 0 will restart both animation.

As long as the animation do not set the same variable, you have the desired effect: both animation play. If the animations set the same variable, you get an interpolation between the two, controlled by the blend value.

Comment: i have like 150 animations in one model, and i need to play them all at once, this solution is ludacris. is there another way to play all of them at once?

Comment: @DumidorDumbleplex Sadly there isn't a lower level API exposed to scripting. From what I'm told, it might be possible from C++, but I haven't look into how. Edit: I'm assuming you mean 150 different animations over the same object, and all in sync, right? - You can play 150 animations with `AnimationPlayer`s as long as they are independent of each other.

Comment: i want to create destruction of an object, so i use blender cell fracture, then i simulate physics, then bake the animation, then it creates n-actions i import the animation into godot 4 and there i see a list of animations where each animation contains n-tracks for each mesh (~150) but keyframes are only for single mesh in single animation

Comment: As i experimented with less meshes and i was successfull to copy keyed tracks from other actions into a single action then set animation player to play that animation and all meshes were animated, but this was a handjob, meaning its a monkeyjob and will not scale for a bigger project :(

Comment: @DumidorDumbleplex If I understand correctly, you have many animations because they are acting on different objects, which you want to play at the same time... But in this question and answer we were talking about playing two animations on the same object (here the problem being that both want to move it so we need a way to blend them). For what you want, you can create a new `AnimationPlayer` with "Animation Playback Track"s that play the animations of the other `AnimationPlayers` concurrently. See the "tricks" I mention here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/205925/10408

Comment: @DumidorDumbleplex Ah, the other of this is that you had to set this manually. But you should be able to use a script to read the animations and add the tracks. It might even run in the editor if you make it a tool script.

Comment: @Thearot thanks for the info, sorry for going off topic, just the information is so scarse.